# Пропали проекты и FTP в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Случается не первый раз, при аварийном выключении компа(свет потух) PhpStorm стартует как при первом запуске(дефолтные настройки).
То есть пропали все проекты и ftp а их не менее 20.
Просто открыть проект можно но при этом нет удаленного сервера так как FTP список пуст.
Собственно вопрос как можно восстановить phpstorm после такого бага?

Comment: Какая система windows, linux, osx? Какая версия phpStorm?
Слетели все настройки или только те которые вы делали при последнем запуске? 
Если только те что при последнем запуске, то восстановит не удасться.

Comment: Windows 7. phpStorm 2016.2.1 тоже такое было и в 2016.1. Слетели настройки за пару месяцев